# CSS:Float and positioning

Tags: css, css-float, positioning

I'm stuck again with css positioning. I would like to create a page which shows one  in the middle, surrounded by 10 other ones. Of course, it should look the same on every resolution (mobiles excluded).

But as i change the screensize, the site keeps on changing its look.

- HTML

  ```
  <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">

      <div class="element" id="element-1">Lorem1</div>
      <div class="element" id="element-2">Ipsum2</div>
      <div class="element" id="element-3">Lorem3</div>
      <div class="element" id="element-4">Ipsum4</div>

      <div class="element" id="element-5">Lorem5</div>
      <span class="break"></span>

      <div class="background" id="background"><span>Neologizmo</span></div>

      <div class="element" id="element-8">Ipsum8</div>

      <div class="element" id="element-9">Lorem9</div>
      <span class="break"></span>
      <div class="element" id="element-10">M10</div>
      <div class="element" id="element-11">M11</div>
      <div class="element" id="element-12">12</div>



  </div>
  ```
- CSS

http://nopaste.info/f6d200c414.html

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: The Text div (Neologizmo) should be centered while all other divs should float around (4 on top, 1 right/left and 4 below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oups, already accepted an answer :$

Well anyway, since I was working on it, here is a generic solution. The idea is that you always have `numberOfsquares/2 -1` squares at the top and bottom, and always one square on the left and one square on the right.

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PyU87/

It will display depending on the wrapper size which depends on the browser size. So this would also work on smartphones.

Comment: unbelievable, thank you for your efforts :) This one is even better

Comment: NP ! The version I gave you is still a coarse version :) You could for example optimize the code by saying that if you have more than x squares, you'd get vertically 2 squares on the side of the center element. In my case, even with 1000 squares (hope you won't try ^^) you'll have 499 on the top and 499 on the bottom with only 1 on the left and 1 on the right.

Answer (score 1):

How does this work? You said you didn't want layouts to change as the screen changes size so I made it use fixed widths and be inside a wrapper so that can't happen.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Pv5E/)

```
#wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

#background {
    width: 212px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

​